# React Native build do app

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Ao criar um projeto do react native e tento executá-lo pelo comando *react-native run-android* esse erro aparece, não importa se é direto no aparelho físico ou no AVD.

Já criei vários projetos e sempre a build falha

Também já tentei compilar o app direto pelo *gradlew assembleDebug*, o erro também aparece.

Acho que é relacionado ao gradle mas não consegui resolver

---

[image: erro]

Comment: Vc está tentando rodar no que? AVD, Genymotion, Aparelho físico?

Comment: Esse projeto já rodava e após vc instalar alguma coisa deu este erro, ou apenas no criar o projeto este já apresenta a falha?

Comment: Vc já rodou outros projetos nesta máquina antes ou esta é a primeira tentativa? Se rodar outro projeto passa, ou qualquer projeto da o erro?

Comment: Melhora essa descrição ai

Comment: @Mateus Já tentei no AVD e direto no aparelho físico, da primeira vez que tento rodar o projeto recém criado o erro aparece, ja criei vários projetos e sempre da o mesmo erro

Comment: @FelipeMarra testa com o comando "npm start" dentro da pasta do projeto.

Comment: @RhadamezGindriHercilio https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eJRjuzDm5etO7T6HgCOEq65jageOmqDU

Comment: @FelipeMarra qual comando vc utilizou para criar o projeto?

Comment: @Mateus react-native init teste

Comment: @FelipeMarra a unica coisa que consigo pensar é que vc tenha errado ao montar o ambiente de desenvolvimento

Comment: Quem sabe, tente criar projeto através de "create-react-native-app NomeProjeto"

Answer (score 1):

Quando abria o projeto no Android Studio ele atualizava o Gradle pra ultima versão, isso ocasionava o erro, acabei de descobrir que é só não aceitar quando sugerir a atualização do 3.1 para o 4.1 que da tudo certo
Muito obrigado a todos que se dispuseram a ajudar